# Lorentz transform derivation

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

From wikipedia page "[Derivations of the Lorentz transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivations_of_the_Lorentz_transformations#Spherical_wavefronts_of_light)",

> $$ \left[ {\gamma^2} - \frac{ \left( 1 - {\gamma^2} \right)^2 c^2}{ {\gamma^2} v^2} \right] x^2 - \left[ 2 {\gamma^2} v + 2 \frac{ \left( 1 - {\gamma^2} \right) c^2}{ v}\right] t x + y^2 + z^2 = \left[ c^2 {\gamma^2} - v^2 {\gamma^2} \right] t^2 $$
>
> Comparing the coefficient of $t^2$ in the above equation with the
> coefficient of $t^2$ in the spherical wavefront equation for frame
> ''O'' produces:
>
> $$c^2 {\gamma^2} - v^2 {\gamma^2} = c^2$$
>
> Equivalent expressions for γ can be obtained by matching the $x^2$
> coefficients or setting the $tx$ coefficient to zero.

It is true that $tx$ term:

$$\left[ 2 {\gamma^2} v + 2 \frac{ \left(1 - {\gamma^2} \right) c^2}{ v}\right]$$

is zero when $c^2 {\gamma^2} - v^2 {\gamma^2} = c^2$. However, $x^2$ term:

$$\left[ {\gamma^2} - \frac{ \left( 1 - {\gamma^2} \right)^2 c^2}{ {\gamma^2} v^2} \right]$$

equals to $\gamma^2+1$ that is not the expected $1$.

I'm doing a basic error of calculus ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have :
$\left[\gamma^{2}-\frac{(1-\gamma^{2})c^{2}}{\gamma^{2}v^{2}}\right]=\left[\gamma^{2}-\frac{(1-\gamma^{2})^{2}}{\gamma^{2}\beta^{2}}\right]\;\;\;\;,$$\;\beta=\frac{v}{c}$

with:  $1-\gamma^{2}=-\gamma^{2}\beta^{2}\;,$
we replace in the previous equation, which gives   :

$\gamma^{2}-\gamma^{2}\beta^{2}=\gamma^{2}(1-\beta^{2})=1$

ps:   The relation $\;c^{2}\gamma^{2}-v^{2}\gamma^{2}=c^{2}\;$ can be written $\gamma^{2}-\beta^{2}\gamma^{2}=1\;\;,\beta=\frac{v}{c}\;\;$ which can be written:

$$\cosh^{2}(\alpha)-\sinh^{2}(\alpha)=1$$
with
\begin{cases}\cosh(\alpha)=\gamma\\sinh(\alpha)=\beta\gamma\end{cases}

or write it $\;\;\frac{1}{\gamma^{2}}+\beta^{2}=1=\cos^{2}(\theta)+ \sin^{2}(\theta)$
with
\begin{cases}\cos(\theta)=\frac{1}{\gamma}\\sin(\theta)=\beta\end{cases}
The previous relation can also be written: $\;\frac{1}{\cos^{2}(\theta)}-\tan^{2}(\theta)=1$
with
\begin{cases}\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}=\gamma\\tan(\theta)=\beta\gamma\end{cases}

it's like we did the transformations: $\;\;\cosh(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}\;\;,\sinh(\alpha)=\tan(\theta)$

what we find in the symmetrical representation or [Loedel diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime_diagram).

Comment: And there are functions that verify these transformations, the Gudermannian function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function

Answer (score 1):

With rapidities, where $(v/c)=\tanh\theta$,
then $\gamma=\cosh\theta$ and so $\gamma (v/c) =\sinh\theta$.

$
\begin{eqnarray}
\left[ {\gamma^2} - \frac{ \left( 1 - {\gamma^2} \right)^2 c^2}{ {\gamma^2} v^2} \right]
&&=
\left[ {\cosh^2\theta} - \frac{ \left( 1 - {\cosh^2\theta} \right)^2 }{ {\sinh^2 \theta}} \right]=\cosh^2\theta - \sinh^2\theta
\end{eqnarray} 
$

Note that the fraction in the second term is non-negative.
While the factor $(1-\cosh^2\theta)=-\sinh^2\theta$ has a minus sign, this gets squared.

Answer (score 0):

It does come out to 1. It's simple algebra. You said
$$c^2 γ^2 - v^2 γ^2 = c^2,$$
from which it follows, immediately, that
$$γ^2 - \frac{\left(1 - γ^2\right)^2 c^2}{γ^2 v^2} = 1.$$

How can we see that? Generalize it by writing $(x,y,z)$ in place of $\left(c^2, v^2, γ^2\right)$; and assume that $z y ≠ 0$. In the context of your query, it's already being assumed that $y ≠ 0$, as well as $x ≠ 0$, and $z ≠ 0$.

Then, under the condition $z y ≠ 0$, what you're saying is the following lemma:
$$x z - y z = x ⇒ z - \frac{(1 - z)^2 x}{z y} = 1,$$
or an equivalent way to write the lemma is:
$$x(z - 1) = y z ⇒ (1 - z)^2 x = z y (z - 1),$$

This holds true, as well. To prove it, assume the equation $x(z - 1) = y z$ on the left and substitute $x(z - 1)$ for $z y$ (which is the same as $y z$) into the equation on the right. The result is immediate.

QED.